# Has Christianity ever separated abortion from feticide?

Tags: abortion

In the didache it says:

> you shall not murder a child by abortion nor kill that which is begotten.
> https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/0714.htm

There currently is a judge in my state who claims that an old law commonly understood to be outlawing abortion only cover feticide instead of surgical abortion.  Now, I'm not so interested in the merits of that particular argument, but was there ever a point in Christian history where Christians would have considered abortion and feticide to be separate things?

Comment: Wouldn't that require ancient Christians to have regarded a human fetus and a human being as separate entities?

Comment: Every abortion, except in the case when the child has already expired in the womb through accident and the corpse must be removed, is a form of feticide. This judge's distinction makes no sense from a moral perspective, though there is perhaps some esoteric common law legal distinction I'm unaware of.

Comment: I think "abortion" has a more general definition which includes miscarriages and stillbirths, so sometimes you will want to use "intentional abortion" or "procured abortion" to refer to the crime of feticide.  I don't think that distinction helps your judge's case, though.

Answer (score 2):

In canon law, "abortion" meant the the "ejection of a immature (pre-viable) fetus"*.
<sub>*"*eiectio fetus immaturi*"; Huser, Roger John, O.F.M., A.B., J.C.L. [*The Crime of Abortion in Canon Law: An Historical Synopsis and Commentary*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8792) p. 90 (PDF p. 102); this work [was cited in *Roe v. Wade*](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/410/113#fn22).</sub>

Abortion incurs automatic (*latæ sententiæ*) [excommunication](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33457), because it deprives the soul of baptism, [which cannot be performed *in utero*](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP068.html#TPQ68A11THEP1).

Killing a post-viable fetus ([craniotomy](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=32858)) fell under the censure of homicide, which incurs the less severe (but still very serious delict) of [irregularity](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34308).

---

It's also to be noted that "child" (בּן, *bên*) in Hebrew can mean an unborn (cf. [Gen. 25:22](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=1&ch=25&l=22#x)) or born (cf. [Gen. 4:17](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=1&ch=4&l=17#x)) child or son. Child sacrifice to Moloch so vehemently condemned in [Leviticus 20:1-5](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=3&ch=20&l=1-5#x), and doubly enforced with capital punishment (both for those who do it and for those who fail to execute those who do it), thus applies to born and unborn people.

Similarly does βρέφος in the New Testament mean a born (cf. [Lk. 18:15](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=49&ch=18&l=15#x)) or unborn (cf. [Lk. 1:41](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=49&ch=1&l=41#x)) child.

<sup>insights courtesy: Randall Terry, [*Divine Correction*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9671) pp. 123-124,132</sup>